# Error when running cmd from powershell script

Tags: powershell, cmd

My script is moving files from one directory to another, once it is done moving the files it then launches a program.
I can launch the program from the short cut, I can launch it from .cmd, but when I have Powershell run it I get an error.
"The following error occured initializing the program:
Error accessing file: Conf/logging.properties
The program will now exit."
I only get this error from Powershell.

I've tried the following but none have worked.

```
 & C:\SMT\App\SMT.exe
 & C:\SMT\App\SMT_Start.cmd
 start-process "cmd.exe" "/c C:\SMT\App\SMT_Start.cmd"
```

the cmd file works when double clicked, looks like:

```
 start C:\SMT\App\SMT.exe -clean
```

The short cut properties look like:
Target: C:\SMT\App\SMT.exe -clean 
Start in: C:\SMT\App
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have this as a complete PowerShell solution. I think that `-WorkingDirectory` is what you need.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\SMT\App\SMT.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\SMT\App" -ArgumentList "-clean" -Wait
```

You can use the `-WorkingDirectory` to ensure the "Start In:" and `-ArgugmentList` for the parameter `-clean` that you are passing. `-Wait` to not continue processing until the command is complete. This depends if the exe closes on its own or not. Experiment with the presence of that switch.